# how to merge two maps using python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

Fairly new to python so this may seem noobish.
I have created two basic maps in .line format (new to me), each showing different features using matplotlib. These maps were converted from separate shapefiles. Now I need to merge these two .line maps into one.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.
TY.

Comment: Hello. Your question would be greatly improved if you shared some of your code so we can see what your maps look like. You might find some of the help pages useful, such as https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Python 3.5** or greater:

```
z = {**x, **y}
```

In **Python 2, (or 3.4 or lower)** write a function:

```
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()   # start with x's keys and values
    z.update(y)    # modifies z with y's keys and values & returns None
    return z

z = merge_two_dicts(x, y)
```

Comment: ``merge_two_dicts`` why is a function required, one liner ``update`` shouldn't it be fine ?

Comment: @sushanth  `z.update(y)` returns `None`. stupid python ..

Answer (score 0):

By 'maps', I assume you mean what are called *mappings* in Python. The most common example is a `dict`.

In recent versions of Python (not sure starting when, but more recent than the 3.4 in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62526728/1450294)), this will work:

```
z = x | y
```

The result will be a new mapping, `z`, which will contain all the elements of `x` and `y`, with `y` winning where there are any duplicates.